# GridView in android studio it stop the app

Tags: android, gridview

I tried many example about grid view but it will be show blank activity or app stopped
I tried to use all the solutions on the site before I wrote my problem but without any correct result
The code appears without errors

can any one help me please

MainActivity

```
package com.safaa.user.grideview;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
GridView gridView;
int images[]={
        R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image3,R.drawable.image4,
        R.drawable.image5,R.drawable.image6,
        R.drawable.image7,R.drawable.image8,
        R.drawable.image9};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gridView=findViewById(R.id.simpleGridView);
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), images);
        gridView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

      gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second_Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("image", images[position]); // put image data in Intent
                startActivity(intent); // start Intent
            }
        });



    }
}
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



      <GridView

            android:id="@+id/simpleGridView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:columnWidth="90dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
package com.safaa.user.grideview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    int images[];
    LayoutInflater inflter;
    public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, int[] images) {
        this.context = applicationContext;
        this.images = images;
        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.activity_gridview, null); // inflate the layout
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon); // get the reference of ImageView
        icon.setImageResource(images[i]); // set logo images
        return view;    }
}
```

activity_gridView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">




    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Second_Activity

```
package com.safaa.user.grideview;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Second_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView selectedImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_);
        selectedImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selectedImage); // init a ImageView
        Intent intent = getIntent(); // get Intent which we set from Previous Activity
        selectedImage.setImageResource(intent.getIntExtra("image", 0)); // get image from Intent and set it in ImageView
    }
    }
```

second_Activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/selectedImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</RelativeLayout >
```

mainfast

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.safaa.user.grideview">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Second_Activity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

buildGradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.safaa.user.grideview"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}
```

Comment: Please include your attempts in the question instead of posting link to a tutorial site

Comment: i did it thank u for note